# How to update django model field every month using cron?

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a model in django in which one Integer field is there. I want to update that field every month using cron job. 
Lets say 1st of every month the field would update .

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where the value should not be populated but calculated dynamically.

Comment: write a management command and  add that in crontab with django setting module, check https://serverfault.com/questions/901495/cron-job-running-a-django-python-command-through-a-virtual-environment-not-worki

Comment: To make my earlier comment more clear: Please explain what you trying to archive with this!

Comment: Let's say I have a django model "Demo" and a IntegerField "data". Now I want the field is automatically update every month of 1st Date. with some predefined field.

Answer (score 2):

```
0 0 1 * *  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_name.settings path_to_virtualenv/bin/python path_to_project/manage.py name_of_management_command.py
```

then in some app write a management command.

Comment: I am not aware about management command, can you share me some resource or link.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html